# kill -3 for C++ application on solaris

Tags: c++, solaris, signals

I have an application written with C++ and running on Solaris. The application does lots of things and sends a heartbeat to a watchdog application for saying "I am alive". If something goes wrong the application does nothing (also does not send heartbeat). In a Java app, `kill -3` helps me to see what is going on. Should I implement a similar functionality MANUALLY using signals for a native (non-java) app? Or is there any alternative way to see what is going on my application internally (thread state etc).

Comment: I'm not too clear what you're asking here - are you looking for a way to kill one process from another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Solaris and Linux support the [gcore](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/manage_core_dump.html#CreateProcess) command to create a core dump of a running process.  Then you can use gdb (or dbx) to analyze the core file.

Comment: Woot the hell, another Strangelove?

Comment: Been using this avatar for years :-)

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way to see what is going on in your native application is to attach a debugger and then examine whatever interests you manually.

If you terminate the application with `kill -3` it will generate a core dump, which can later be manually examined with a debugger in a similar way.

If you want specific information logged/... in reaction to the signal sent by `kill -3` you have to implement that yourself.